# Working with larger inventor models in Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm working with a template inventor model that's approximately 300MB which I maintain in appbundle. As forge restricts the size of appbundle to 100MB, I'm unable to upload the appbundle and work with Design Automation API. Is there any possible workaround to work with larger inventor models?

Answer (score 0):

I think these could be your options:

1. **Zip** up the files and **unzip** them to the working folder of the **work item**
2. Split the content into multiple **app bundles** and reference all of them from the **activity**
3. Combination of 1&2

Answer (score 0):

You can always provide this template inventor model as one input argument of WorkItem, Design Automation will download this template for each WorkItem.

If this still cannot fit your case, please contact aps.help@autodesk.com. We can evaluate the max permitted size of the AppBundle for your case.